# How can i left and right swipe by array Object in ZLSwipeableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example first card green color second card white color third card yellow color. So first, we swipe right .so now top view is white card after we swipe left so now top view is green card how can it possible

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebTgl.png)